# PC shutdown suddenly and idk the cause

Tags: windows, windows-10, hardware-failure, shutdown, troubleshooting

I have a desktop PC I bought 10 years ago and I use it as a "server", so it's always on.

It started to suddenly shutdown few months ago, after few days or weeks being on (last time I powered it on, it lasted 46 hours to shutdown).

**So, I think I have a hardware issue that is making my PC suddenly shutdown.**

After that, I made some tests:

- I searched in Windows event viewer and didn't found anything weird.
- I stressed it with CPU-Z and watched temperature with SpeedFan, but it reached no more than 65 ºC.

Power outages weren't a problem, because I have an UPS. There are just a few power outages per year, if any. But my PC went down more than 10 times.

**I also configured auto power in BIOS and manually tested it (powering on and off my electric installation) and it worked.
But now isn't working auto power on. That should be a hint of what is the issue here.**

I dont live at the place my computer is located, so I only can rely on logs. Also it's annoying because I have to drive there and power it on every time I need it. But I have physical access to it, so I can try anything you suggest.

I thought some ideas:

- Looking for more sophisticated temperature tests (Prime95 or something).
- Windows RAM test.
- Also scanning for malware (it shouldnt have any, because the system is updated and noone can access it physically, other than me).

**What would be other possible causes and what are the tests I could do?**

I know I should be using Linux for this, but Windows worked just fine for years.

PC is an MSI with AMD processor and RAID SSDs (two mirrored, bought 2 years ago).
It uses Windows 10 x64.

Comment: And your question is?????

Comment: @davidgo i edited it now. I want u tell me more possible causes and tests to do. Or ur opinion on what u think is more probable

Comment: We can't realistically help you if you are not even at your machine.

Comment: You mentionef the stress tests you need to do but cant be bothered to even fire up an alternative OS.  Not sure how we can help. My guess (hust a guess) is a dodgy power supply

Comment: Gamer speak is not the adequate language for a global audience where English is not the mother tongue. Why helping someone with an understandable answer who does not bother to write full words when asking?!

Comment: @Ramhound I have physical access to it.
Just I dont live with it, so I can tell exactly what happens when it shutdown.
I mean, I cant hear noises, nor see anything, because Im not there when it shutdowns

Comment: @davidgo I'm saying I'm using Windows 10 as main OS and it worked fine for almost 10 years on that machine.
Im open to boot with some live OS (i.e. some Linux) to test things.
But I dont consider replacing my main OS would solve the issue

Comment: @davidgo nice suggestion, thanks!
Then I will try another power supply (luckily I have one without use)

Comment: @r2d3 wooow! we have some ad hóminem here.
Ok, now I edited my answer and no more "gamer speak". It's just handy to write less.
However, any help is welcome!

Comment: Guys, I edited my question and added some valuable information in bold.
Auto power on BIOS configuration worked during manual test, but it doesn't work when my PC suddenly shutdowns.
I mean, if I disconnect grid and reconnect, my PC power on automatically.
But if I left it and it suddenly shutdown, then it doesn't automatically power on.
I think that's a hint of what's the issue

Comment: In addition to running memtest, have you looked at your windows settings - eg Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced Ssytem Setings -> Advanced -> Settings and ensure you are writing events to system log and "Automatic Restart" is disabled?   Similarly, have you checked the system log?   Also, have you looked at your BIOS to check if there is the option to automatically restart on power on?

Comment: When your system reaches a state where a BSOD is required and generates a system dump, is your system configured to restart or simply shut down automatically? My suggestion is instead of having to drive to the system to diagnose this problem, you will have to likely move the machine in order to troubleshoot this problem.  You also eliminate it's current location as the cause of the system instability.

Comment: @Ramhound I did that. I just said that I had to drive to justify the need of solutions.
But good advice. Also good tip eliminate it's current location as a possible cause

Comment: @davidgo I saw the setting you said and it automatic restart was enabled.
The BIOS option was enabled, because that was the first thing I founded and turned on.
But it wasn't working...
However, I found the causes and solved the problem (I will post my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by cleaning my pc, applying thermal paste, adding a case cooler, and switching my CPU cooler for a better one.  It reached 85 ºC under CPU-Z stress, but now just 70 ºC. I saw broken Windows configs (not opening), missing drivers, and Windows Update not working.

I concluded that temperature was the root cause, and Windows's broken image was its symptom.

Maybe it was updating Windows and it shutdown because of the high temperatures, and that made a broken OS image.
Believe me: that oven was 80 ºC during a simple LAN backup of 50 GB folder. Even it shut down!  But I noticed all this after moving my pc to my home to diagnose and repair.

Comment: "Maybe it was updating Windows, and it shutdown because of high temperature, and that made a broken OS image." - While it's possible the system did shutdown, Windows has a substantial amount of safe guards to prevent system corruption while a Windows Update is being installed. If installing proper cooling solved the problems, the instability was simply due to heat. BLUF: You likely didn't actually have a "broken Windows image" your system was just not stable due to the heat.